# Why is this CSS code overflowing inside my inner box even though it fits my outer box?

Tags: css, overflow

So I created a box with 2 div tags, namely: outer div and box div.

The total width(content block) of my outer div is 600w+50padLeft+50padRight= 700px. Meanwhile the total width of my box div (containing block) is 500w+98padL+98padR+4border = 700px.

Yet, my box is overflowing in the outer div.

Here is the image:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/183721425@N02/48599642452/in/dateposted-public/

```css
aside,
article,
section,
header,
footer,
nav {
  display: block;
}

div,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  background: #ccc;
}

.outer {
  /* TOTAL WIDTH: 700px */
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #9CF;
  padding: 50px;
}

.box {
  background: #B7D19C;
  /* TOTAL WIDTH: 700px */
  width: 500px;
  padding: 98px;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

p {
  background: #FF9;
  height: 100%;
  /* here */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Here we'll need to calculate the width of this interior div element. This may seem simple at first, but as we begin to add box model properties, and as the overall width of the parent element and the div conflict with one another, we'll need to understand
      how each of the properties combine to effect the overall width (and height) of page elements.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: an element is only included in the content-box of it's container ... so the inner element will not be inluded in the padding so you only have 500px for the inner to place 700px, it's not 700px inside 700px like you think

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-sizng:border-box` property.

> It defines how the width and height of an element are calculated, should they include padding and borders, or not. Margin is not considered. Usually the size (width or height) of the element not include border or padding

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>calculating element dimensions</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <style>
    aside,
    article,
    section,
    header,
    footer,
    nav {
      display: block;
    }
    
    div,
    p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    html {
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    .outer {
      /* TOTAL WIDTH: 700px */
      width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #9CF;
      padding: 50px;
    }
    
    .box {
      background: #B7D19C;
      /* TOTAL WIDTH: 700px */
      width: 500px;
      padding: 98px;
      border: 2px black solid;
    }
    
    p {
      background: #FF9;
      height: 100%;
      /* here */
    }
    /*add styles here*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Here we'll need to calculate the width of this interior div element. This may seem simple at first, but as we begin to add box model properties, and as the overall width of the parent element and the div conflict with one another, we'll need to
        understand how each of the properties combine to effect the overall width (and height) of page elements.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

Your issue is with the box model itself as by default the `border` and the `padding` are not included in the actual elements width :

- `.outer` has a `width` of `600px` and has a `50px` of `padding` (total `width` is `600px + 50px right padding + 50px left padding = 700px`) so the `.box` will be shifted `50px` to the right.
- `.box` has `500px` for the `width`, `98px` for the `padding` and a `2px` `border` which results in a `500px + 98px right padding + 98px left padding + 2px left border + 2px right border =700px`.
- the `width`s are equal but don't forget about the `50px` of `padding` on the `.outer` that results on an overflow.

**Solution :**

The solution is very simple, add `box-sizing: border-box` on the two `div`s (better to use it on all the elements) which includes the `padding` and `border` on the `width` (meaning the `padding` and `border` won't overflow the declared `width`).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /** that's it ! **/
}

aside,
article,
section,
header,
footer,
nav {
  display: block;
}

div,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  background: #ccc;
}

.outer {
  /* TOTAL WIDTH: 700px */
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #9CF;
  padding: 50px;
}

.box {
  background: #B7D19C;
  /* TOTAL WIDTH: 700px */
  width: 500px;
  padding: 98px;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

p {
  background: #FF9;
  height: 100%;
  /* here */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Here we'll need to calculate the width of this interior div element. This may seem simple at first, but as we begin to add box model properties, and as the overall width of the parent element and the div conflict with one another, we'll need to understand
      how each of the properties combine to effect the overall width (and height) of page elements.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So let's say padding and border is not included in actual elements width. Then that would mean outer div will be total of 600px width. While box div will be 500px width. so 600=500 the box div should fit right? But it's not coz it's overflowing. Please clear my understanding.

Comment: outer div is `600 + 50 * 2 = 700px` and the box is `500 + 98 * 2 + 2 * 2 = 700` and as the the outer has a `padding-left` of 50px the box will be pushed to the right by 50px so when using `border-box` we ensure  having the padding and the borders calculated into the width wich is 600 for the outer and 500 for box no matter how padding and border are.

Comment: but the outer and box div already have the same width as you discussed (700px) where padding -left and padding-right is included in the total width. So even if the outer div push it with padding, it will not affect the box div coz they have same width and they fit.

Comment: Like if I put my tv box(200) in the other box(200) ~ same width... it will fit coz they have the same width unless if my tv box is too big to fit the other box...

Comment: @user11880836 the padding is included only when using `border-box`.